# How to prevent rightmost inline element from wrapping or overflowing in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I give up!

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Ws5Ts/1/

**Desired behavior**:

1. The indicator number is displayed inline with the customer's name (I don't want it fixed to the right of the `item` div)
2. When the window is resized or if the customer has a very long name the indicator should NOT overflow, but stay at the right side of the `item` div while the customer's name overflows

I've been at this for the past two hours trying to use all different kinds of wrapping `divs` with different positioning but I can't get anything to work exactly how I want it to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've spent WAY too much time on this.

**Possible solution**: http://jsfiddle.net/Ws5Ts/17/

**Approach:**

1. Reverse the order the of text and indicator and then switch the `direction` to `rtl` so that the text overflows to the left. This keeps the indicator where I want it but the text is now overflowing in the wrong direction.
2. Make the overflowing text hidden and use it as a spacer. Set the duplicate visible absolute-positioned text within a container that has a margin to account for the indicator and set nowrap, hidden overflow and text-overflow on that container.

This seems to work in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE9.

Anyone else have a less convoluted approach?

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the indicator outside your current div?
Just made a really quick example of what I mean here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ws5Ts/3/

My classes aren't very performance correct, but I'm off to bed :)

```
'
```

edit: See my comment about margin-left if that suits your layout better

Comment: Read OP's question: *"I don't want it fixed to the right of the item div"*

Comment: So give it margin-left:-25px; ? (arbitrary number)

Comment: @DC_ I got thing the same way as daniel, that it was about position fixed

Comment: @daniel The name will be a variable length... that's why I need the indicator to be in the flow next to it on the same line. Setting a fixed margin or left position won't work.